# How to get the current values of RadGrid Columns

Tags: asp.net

I am using the follwing code.
 **in .aspx:**

```
 function AccessOnclient() {  
    debugger;
                    var grid = $find("<%= dg_InvPat.ClientID %>");  
                    if (grid) {  
                        var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
                        var sumtemp = 0;
                        var Rows = MasterTable.get_dataItems();  
                        for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {  
                            var row = Rows[i];  
                                                  var RadNumericTextBox1 = row.findControl("txt_projInv");
                            if (RadNumericTextBox1.get_value()) 
                              {
                             sumtemp =sumtemp + RadNumericTextBox1.get_value();
                              }
                              }
                            for (var i = 0; i < Rows.length; i++) {  
                            var row = Rows[i];  
                                                   var RadNumericTextBox1 = row.findControl("txt_projInv");
                            var valinv=RadNumericTextBox1.get_value();
                            var res=Math.round((valinv/sumtemp)*100);
                            var revpat = MasterTable.get_dataItems()[i].findElement("lbl_revpat");//access the Label control
                            revpat.innerText = res;
                              }

                         document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_b1").click();



                    }  


     }
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
        <div id="content">
            <table class="table_Style" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 15%">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server">Financial Year</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <Telerik:RadComboBox AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="ddl_year" Width="200px"
                            MarkFirstMatch="true" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="List">
                        </Telerik:RadComboBox>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="cmd_go" runat="server" Text="View" CausesValidation="true"
                            ValidationGroup="btnSubmit"></asp:Button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvyear" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Financial Year"
                            ControlToValidate="ddl_year" ValueToCompare="Select" Operator="NotEqual" ValidationGroup="btnSubmit"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="table_Style" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <Telerik:RadGrid ID="dg_InvPat" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                            HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" Width="100%" ShowStatusBar="True" AllowPaging="True"
                            AllowSorting="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="False" PageSize="5">
                            <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
                            <ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="true" OpenInNewWindow="True" IgnorePaging="true"
                                FileName="InvPattern">
                            </ExportSettings>
                            <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="None" CommandItemSettings-ShowRefreshButton="false"
                                CommandItemSettings-ShowAddNewRecordButton="false">
                                <RowIndicatorColumn>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                                </RowIndicatorColumn>
                                <ExpandCollapseColumn>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
                                </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                                <NoRecordsTemplate>
                                    <font color="red">No Records Available</font>
                                </NoRecordsTemplate>
                                <Columns>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="NOTIF1" DataField="NOTIF1" HeaderText="As Per Notification" Visible ="false" >
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="NOTIF" DataField="NOTIF" HeaderText="As Per Notification">
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CAT" DataField="CAT" HeaderText="Pattern Category">
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="INVESTMENT" DataField="INVESTMENT" HeaderText="Act Investment">
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="LIMITID" DataField="LIMITID" HeaderText="Limit Id"
                                        Visible="false">
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="TRUSTPAT1" DataField="TRUSTPAT1" HeaderText="Trust Pattern" Visible="false">
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="TRUSTPAT" DataField="TRUSTPAT" HeaderText="Trust Pattern">
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SHORTAGE" DataField="SHORTAGE" HeaderText="Shortfall/Excess">
                                    </Telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                    <Telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Project Investment">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                             <Telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txt_projInv" runat="server" EmptyMessage="" IncrementSettings-InterceptMouseWheel="false"
                                                                     SkinID="RadTextYellow" Type="Number" DataType="System.Int64"
                                                                    AutoPostBack="false" MaxLength="8" Text='<%# Bind("investment") %>'>
                                                                    <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" GroupSeparator="" />
                                                                     <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="AccessOnclient" OnValueChanged="AccessOnclient"/> 
                                                                </Telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </Telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                                    <Telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Revised Pattern">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                           <asp:Label ID="lbl_revpat" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("trustpat1") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </Telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                                </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </Telerik:RadGrid>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="tr1">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" >
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <br/>
                                    <div id="divgraph1" runat="server" >
                                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlnum" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="False" style="height:400px">
                                             <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblhead" runat="server" Font-Size="10" ForeColor="#000033"
                            Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Label ID="lbltotal" runat="server"  Font-Size="10" ForeColor="#000033"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label Width="100%" ID="lblmess" SkinID="lblErr" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <asp:Button id="b1" runat="server" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <Telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="RadFormDecorator1" runat="server" DecoratedControls="Default"
                            Skin="Sunset" Style="margin-bottom: 0px" />
                        <Telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager2" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" VisibleStatusbar="false"
                            ReloadOnShow="true" runat="server" Modal="true">
                        </Telerik:RadWindowManager>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

**in .aspx.vb:**

```
#Region "Namespaces"
Imports Telerik.Web.UI
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports InfoSoftGlobal.InfoSoftGlobal
#End Region

Partial Class iv
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

#Region "Declarations"
    Dim objEntry_ml As ClsPF_BE
    Dim objEntry_bll As ClsPF_BLL
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim objCom_ml As Common_ml
    Dim objCom_bll As Common_bll
    Dim UserSysId As Long
    Public UnitID As Integer
    Public UnitName As String
    Dim strXML As String
#End Region

#Region "PageEvents"

    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        AddHandler Master.PageEvent, AddressOf Page_Load
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Master.UnitChange = True Then
            Response.Redirect("iv.aspx")
        End If
        Master.PageHeadingTitle = "Pattern"

        If Not Session("UserSysId") Is Nothing Then
            UnitID = Session("UnitId")
            UnitName = Session("UnitName")
            UserSysId = Session("UserSysId")

        Else
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?Status=S")
        End If

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            LoadYear()

        End If

        lblmess.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Protected Sub cmd_go_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd_go.Click
        LoadGrid()
        Literal1.Text = DrawGraph() 
        pnlnum.Visible = True
        divgraph1.Visible = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub LoadGrid()
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        Try

            objEntry_ml = New ClsPF_BE
            objEntry_bll = New ClsPF_BLL
            Dim sReturnMessage As String = ""
            objEntry_ml.FinYear_code = ddl_year.SelectedValue
            ds = objEntry_bll.bll_Invpattern(objEntry_ml, UserSysId, sReturnMessage)
            dg_InvPat.DataSource = ds
            dg_InvPat.DataBind()

            ds = Nothing


            If dg_InvPat.Items.Count > 1 Then

                lblmess.Visible = False
                divgraph1.Visible = True
            Else

                lblmess.Text = "No records found for the year" & ddl_year.Text
                lblmess.Visible = True
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
    Sub LoadYear()
        objEntry_ml = New ClsPF_BE
        objEntry_bll = New ClsPF_BLL
        ds = objEntry_bll.fillfinyear(objEntry_ml)
        ddl_year.DataSource = ds
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ddl_year.DataValueField = ds.Tables(0).Columns(0).Caption
            ddl_year.DataTextField = ds.Tables(0).Columns(1).Caption
            ddl_year.DataBind()
            If ddl_year.Items.Count > 0 Then
                ddl_year.Items.Insert(0, New RadComboBoxItem("Select", ""))
            End If
        End If
        objEntry_ml = Nothing
        objEntry_bll = Nothing
        ds = Nothing
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Functions"

    Public Function DrawGraph() As String
        Try
            Dim ds As DataSet
            Dim dv As DataView
            Dim dr As DataRowView

            Dim sReturnMessage As String = ""
            objEntry_ml = New ClsPF_BE
            objEntry_bll = New ClsPF_BLL


            strXML = "<chart palette='4' pieSliceDepth='30' pieRadius='120'  CAPTION='Investment Pattern(In %)' bgcolor='#e5e5e5'  outCnvBaseFont='verdana' outCnvBaseFontSize='11' showPercentageValues='1' bgAngle='360' showBorder='1' baseFont='Arial' baseFontSize='11' baseFontColor ='000000'>"


            For Each item As GridDataItem In dg_InvPat.Items
                Dim txt As Label = DirectCast(item.FindControl("lbl_revpat"), Label)
                Dim aa As String = txt.Text

                strXML = (strXML & ("<set label='" & (Server.HtmlEncode(item.Cells(4).Text) & ("' value='" & aa & "'/>"))))
            Next

            strXML = (strXML & "</chart>")

            Return FusionCharts.RenderChartHTML("FusionCharts/Charts/Pie3D.swf", "", Server.UrlEncode(strXML.ToString), "Percentage", "500", "350", False)

        Catch ex As Exception

            divgraph1.Visible = False
            lblmess.Text = "You have no rights to view this report"
            lblmess.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            lblhead.Text = ""
            lbltotal.Text = ""
        End Try

    End Function


#End Region


    Protected Sub b1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles b1.Click
        Literal1.Text = DrawGraph()
        pnlnum.Visible = True
        divgraph1.Visible = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here when i chnge the textbox in templatecolumn in radgrid, the corresponding value is stored in the label(GridTemplateColumn of Radgrid). That is written in javascript. But the corresponding fusion chart is not shown. When i debug, the new values(calculated by javascript) are not taken into account. Only the values which is being bound in the grid will be plotted in the fusion chart.

In DrawGraph() function  i have used the label named as **Revised pattern**(GridTemplateColumn) value as `<set label` value. But the new value is not coming. 
Eg. if i give 600 in **Project Investment** column, the corresponding percentage 42 is coming in **Revised pattern**(GridTemplateColumn). But the fusion chart is not changed.
 How the problem can be solved?

ANYONE PLEASE HELP ME.........

Comment: "Please give me the solution" is not a good way to end a question. You need to perform your own attempts and let us know what you have done first.

Comment: I am not sure but can you try using textbox instead labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to go for the textbox instead label

---

Because textbox are server control and label have problem always getting values 
like if you are using update panel or so.....
so textbox will be a best option to use